# How to stop the ticks using a breed in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I want to create a Democracy Model. I have created 4 breed for that. One for people who will vote, the rest 2 for parties. In my code, I wand to stop the model when any of the parties reach a total number of 100 votes. I can't figure it out. Please help me. Here's my code:

```
breed [people p]
breed [party1 p1]
breed [party2 p2]
breed [party3 p3]

party1-own [vote]
party2-own [vote]
party3-own [vote]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-people
  setup-parties
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches [
    ifelse pxcor >= 4 and pycor >= 6
    [set pcolor white]
    [set pcolor brown]
  ]
end

to setup-people
  set-default-shape people "person"
  create-people number-of-people
  ask people [setxy random-float -16 random-float -16]
end

to setup-parties
  set-default-shape party1 "person"
  set-default-shape party2 "person"
  set-default-shape party3 "person"
  create-party1 1
  create-party2 1
  create-party3 1
  ask party1 [setxy 15 -1]
  ask party2 [setxy 15 -3]
  ask party3 [setxy 15 -5]
  ask party1 [set color blue]
  ask party2 [set color green]
  ask party3 [set color yellow]
end

to go
  start-voting
  ask party1 [
    if (vote) >= 100 [stop]
  ]
  ask party2 [
    if (vote) >= 100 [stop]
  ]
  ask party3 [
    if (vote) >= 100 [stop]
  ]
  tick
end

to start-voting
  let x random 3
  ifelse x = 2
  [ask party3 [set vote vote + 1]]
  [
    ifelse x = 1
    [ask party2 [set vote vote + 1]]
    [ask party1 [set vote vote + 1]]
  ]

  ifelse show-votes?
  [
    ask party1 [set label vote]
    ask party2 [set label vote]
    ask party3 [set label vote]
  ]
  [
    ask party1 [set label ""]
    ask party2 [set label ""]
    ask party3 [set label ""]
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem with your stop procedure is that a turtle can only `stop` its own role in a procedure. check out the [procedure manual](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#buttons) regarding buttons for a more thorough explanation, where it is stated:

> In a turtle or patch forever button, the button won't stop until every turtle or patch stops -- a single turtle or patch doesn't have the power to stop the whole button

So it looks like what's happening is that your first group is stopping the procedure, but since that happens *after* voting happens, **and** the other turtles are not stopped, the votes will continue to be added and the procedure will continue to run. In this case, it's probably better to have a global-level stop condition, as below. Note that when the observer queries a turtle using `of`, the variable is returned in a list, so `item 0` is needed below.

```
to go
  start-voting
  if ( item 0 [vote] of party1 > 100 ) or ( item 0 [vote] of party2 > 100 ) or ( item 0 [vote] of party3 > 100 )  [
    stop
  ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: Thank you. That was very much helpful